# Why can't we declare a static variable within a structure in the C programming language?

Tags: c

Why can't we declare a static variable within a structure in the C programming language?

Comment: Because ISO C standard says that you cannot. But if you tell why you think you need it, it might be possible to provide a workaround for whatever it'll be.

Comment: Even in C++ there is no such thing like a `static` variable inside a structure. These are `static` members, and it is really a pity that C++ overloads the `static` keyword for yet another completely different semantic. In particular, it means the contrary of `static` in file or function scope, namely a symbol that is globally visible. I really don't see any use of that. If you'd asked for `extern`, this *could* make sense in C, but this would be different story.

Comment: @Jens: `static` in function scope means that all invocations of the function share the same instance of a variable.  Similarly, `static` in a class means that all instances of the class share the same instance of the field.  Seems to me that reusing the keyword is perfectly well-motivated.

Comment: @John: I didn't say that it was not motivated, it is just unfortunate. Something like `common`, `global` whatever, would have been more appropriate. And the history already starts in C with the two different meanings (file vs. function scope), and continues in C99 with the use of `static` for a lower bound on the array size in function parameters. All this is superfluously complicating the language by adding context sensitivity to keywords.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++, a struct is basically a class with all members public, so a static variable makes good sense there.

In C, a struct is a contiguous chunk of memory with fields. A static variable can not be created without changing that (as to implement a static you need to refer to a single memory location from all structs of that type), and that would be a big difference in complexity without much benefit.

Comment: I'd sy this is a pretty strong reason.

Comment: Yet I could have only had static members in the struct which would've made it contiguous

Answer (score 5):

Because C is not C++.

Because the C standard does not permit it.

Because it has no meaningful interpretation in C.

Answer (score 3):

**Static variables** should not be declared inside structure.The reason is C compiler requires the entire structure elements to be placed together (i.e.) memory allocation for structure members should be contiguous. It is possible to declare structure inside the function (stack segment) or allocate memory dynamically(heap segment) or it can be even global (BSS or data segment). Whatever might be the case, all structure members should reside in the same memory segment because the value for the structure element is fetched by counting the offset of the element from the beginning address of the structure. Separating out one member alone to data segment defeats the purpose of static variable.

*It is possible to have an entire structure as static.*

reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Because in c we can't access static variable with stucture name.
In c++ we can access static member variable with class name,like below.

ClassName::staticVariableName

'C' stucture don't provide such facility.